# Registering a web-domain with different TLD from an existing company

Tags: domains, domain-registration

I am planning to buy a web-domain for myself. I am looking for a particular word combination and in the process I notice many combinations are already taken up in `.com` TLD. If someone owns **example.com** (example is their company name), can I buy **example.net** if its available or is it illegal to use one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you wouldn't be infringing on an actual registered trademark or similar, if a domain is available for purchase, then it's up for grabs. (Even if it *is* an infringement, there's really nothing stopping you from buying the domain, but the owner may be able to file a claim.)